# Which if else code should I use, single line or multiple lines?

Tags: flutter, dart

There are two types of `if` function codes:

```
condition1 ? function1 : condition2 ? function2 : function3;
```

---

```
if (condition1) {
  function1
} else {
  if (condition2) {
    function2
  } else {
    function3
  }
}
```

I don't know what is the correct way to use the `if else` function code, I hope everyone can tell me.

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

Which `if else` code should I use, single line or multiple lines? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's up to you, boths are fine.

Comment: Hi @Eugenio thanks for your comment! So what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two codes?

Comment: One line: You can use it if you're focus on code efficiency, it has a lot of less lines.
Multiple line: I like to use this because is very clear about any case, it's better to read.

So, you can choose what the most important for you.

Comment: @Eugenio thank you I know which one I should choose now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two are *not* "different styles of `if`".

The first one is the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator). As the term `operator` suggests, it is used to produce a value.

The second one is the flow control statement `if`. It does not produce any value, it changes your program's flow.

So which one should you use? The one that fits your goal best. Do you need a value? The operator. Do you need to change your program flow? The flow control statement.

Try to reproduce this `if` statement with a ternary operator:

```dart
if (trafficlight.current == red) {
  stopVehicle();
}
```

You cannot. Not without adding pointless waste. Because this is *flow control*.

On the other hand, this:

```dart
var newSpeed = (trafficlight.current == red) ? 0 : this.MaxSpeed;
```

Would be very convoluted to write as an `if` statement. Because it is generating a value.

So pick what is best for your program. It's not a "style" to follow blindly. It is a *decision* you should make for every one of those instances.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! This answer has a good explanation. I know which one I should choose now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have a question. Should I use the first or second code to return the widget?

Comment: Depends... if your Widget is a value that you can produce depending on a single statement, go for the ternary operator. If it needs more flow control, go for the `if`.

Comment: Thanks! You have been a great help to me! Thanks again!